# Postgres pg_dumpall failing

Tags: postgresql, backup

Recently on my debian server with postgres 10.6, `pg_dumpall` has started to fail with the following error:

```
su - postgres -c pg_dumpall | gzip > /temp/directory/postgres_backup.gz
```

```
pg_dumpall: query failed: ERROR:  type "pg_catalog.bool" does not exist
pg_dumpall: query was: SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false)
```

I'm just not sure where to start to diagnose the issue as the script was working fine.

Comment: Please share your `pg_dumpall` script. Thanks.

Comment: Which Postgres version? Are the server and `pg_dumpall` tool the same version? Does `select * from pg_type where typname = 'bool';` return anything?

Comment: @LuanHuynhAdded command being run to original post

Comment: @CL. postgres 10.6, pg_dumpall is from the 10.6 version of postgres as well.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade from 10.2 to something higher?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name No it's always been 10.6 since I setup the server.

Answer (score 0):

Wiping out all the tables and restoring from an older backup did not work either.

pg_dumpall just wanted to run this command, `SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false)` and I have no idea how to turn it off or adjust it.

My solution was to remove postgresql-10.6 and reinstall it.  After restoring my old sql, pg_dumpall was working successfully again.